# How to split an array into evenly sized chucks and perform the same calculation on each chuck

Tags: python, arrays, out-of-memory

I have an array called `start_similarity_results` with size 47000*90000, with each element is a float number between 0 and 1. For each row, I need to find out the col indices at which position the float number is greater than a threshold, and from all these qualified col indices, I will randomly pick out one. Now my code looks like:

```
    out_start = np.ones(47000)*-1
    cur_row_start = 0
    col_list_start = []
    for r_start, c_start in zip(*(np.nonzero(start_similarity_results>=similarity_threshold))):
        if r_start == cur_row_start:
            col_list_start.append(c_start)
        else:
            random.shuffle(col_list_start)
            if len(col_list_start) != 0:
                out_start[cur_row_start] = col_list_start[0]
            cur_row_start = r_start
            col_list_start = []
            col_list_start.append(c_start)

    random.shuffle(col_list_start)
    if len(col_list_start) != 0:
        out_start[cur_row_start] = col_list_start[0]
```

So in the end, I can get an array called `out_start` with size 47000*1, 47000 is the number of rows *in order*, and for each row, there is a col index which I will use this array for future processing.

However, when I run my code, I meet **memory error** at

```
for r_start, c_start in zip(*(np.nonzero(start_similarity_results>=similarity_threshold)))
```

which seems that my array (47000*90000) is too big for the processor so it just stops. So I am wondering whether I can split my array into several parts and run them in parallel on multi cores. The important thing is that I will get the same `out_start` as it is now.

Comment: What is a simple input array for your function, and what would the corresponding output array look like?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get what you mean exactly. Details are: The 47000*90000 array contains all similarity values between two matrixs. I then just use this 47000*90000 array to find a qualified (over threshold) col for each row and memory error occurs at for r_start, c_start in zip(*(np.nonzero(start_similarity_results>=similarity_threshold)))

Comment: I need to know what your expected input and output will look like so that I can try and create a less memory-intensive solution.  If you don't provide code that I can actually run, you need to at least provide a simple example of the input and the expected output.  As in, provide a 5x5 example input array and the output array you would expect to get from that 5x5 array.

Comment: ah okay, lets make a 6*4 input array: array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.02], [0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.002], [0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6], [0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0.65], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]]), and the threshold is 0.3, expected output to be: array([3, 2, 1, 1, 0, -1])

Comment: With that input, wouldn't you want your output to be [3,2,0,0,0,-1]? Also you should edit your post with this information so it will be easier to read.

Comment: Oh never mind.  I see, you want a random column above threshold, not the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, multiprocessing or threading is not going to help you with a memory error.

Here's a function that I think should solve your problem, if I'm understanding it correctly.  For each row, it gets a random column that is above threshold, or else -1:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def get_cols(x, thresh):
    out = []
    for row in x:
        above = np.where(row>=thresh)
        if above[0].any():
            out.append(random.choice(above[0]))
        else:
            out.append(-1)
    return np.array(out)
```

And here's the example input that you gave and the output:

```
x = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.02],
              [0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.002], [0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6],
              [0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0.65], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]])

print get_cols(x, 0.3)
# [ 3  2  0  0  0 -1]
# [ 3  2  0  1  0 -1]
# [ 3  2  0  3  0 -1]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Actually, I also try to use a forloop for each row and it solves the problem. Similar as you do but your code seems clearer :D